# How to configure a view accessible on user's profile only by that user

Tags: views, 8

I have a view listing the nodes a user created on /user/{user}/mycontent.

How should I configure the view so that other users won't have access it?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want them to see their own content instead of the user which profile they are currently viewing, you need to add a **contextual filter**

skip to 8:52 and watch [Views Relationships and Contextual Filters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRWtpcUm9pI)

Note: this is for drupal 7, but I imagine the drupal 8 views look the same.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that one out. But I wasn't able to properly configure the View. But I'll check the video, thanks.

Comment: So I watched it and he didn't do the validation I need.

Comment: validation? what do you mean?

Comment: Re-red the second sentance of the question.

Comment: I've edited the question since the second issue was easily solved.

Comment: You need to edit the access. Not sure if changing it to authenticated user and admin is good enough for you (anonymous users can't see it) http://s28.postimg.org/p7dk3wugt/help.jpg. If you want that only the logged in user can view it in their own profile I guess you would need to use the php option and write a conditional IF statement or something.

Comment: My conclusion is that I better create a route manually, with proper access validation, and just use the Views block.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the view visible only to the users who are watching their own user page, you cannot merely achieve that using the settings a view has for the access. You need to compare the user ID of the currently logged-in user with the user ID of the user object associated with the user page; that doesn't involve checking the logged-in user has a specific permission (although you can additionally check for the user having a specific permission), nor a specific role.

You can use the code shown on [Drupal 8 Views: How to set as admin path](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/drupal-8-views-how-set-admin-path) as start for your code.

#### my_module.services.yml

```
  services:
    my_module.route_subscriber:
      class: Drupal\my_module\Routing\RouteSubscriber
      tags:
        - { name: event_subscriber }

    my_module.access_view_checker:
      class: Drupal\my_module\Access\AccessViewChecker
      arguments: ['@current_user']
      tags:
        - { name: access_check, applies_to: _access_view_check }
```

#### my_module/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Class RouteSubscriber.
 *
 * @package Drupal\my_module\Routing
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    $admin_routes = ['view.my_example_view.page_1'];
    foreach ($collection->all() as $name => $route) {
      if (in_array($name, $admin_routes)) {
        $route->setRequirement('_access_view_check', TRUE);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See also [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones) and [Access checking on routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes) to understand which code to use for the access control class.